# Convert unicode to characters in a file using Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, encoding, character-encoding

I have this string in a **code.txt** file.

```
"class Solution {\u000Apublic:\u000A    vector\u003Cvector\u003Cint\u003E\u003E insert(vector\u003Cvector\u003Cint\u003E\u003E\u0026 intervals, vector\u003Cint\u003E\u0026 newInterval) {\u000A        int len \u003D intervals.size()\u003B\u000A        int index \u003D 0\u003B\u000A        vector\u003Cvector\u003Cint\u003E \u003E ans\u003B\u000A        \u000A\u000A        while(index \u003C len \u0026\u0026 intervals[index][1] \u003C newInterval[0]) ans.push_back(intervals[index++])\u003B\u000A        \u000A        while(index \u003C len \u0026\u0026 intervals[index][0] \u003C\u003D newInterval[1]) {\u000A            newInterval[0] \u003D min(intervals[index][0], newInterval[0])\u003B\u000A            newInterval[1] \u003D max(intervals[index][1], newInterval[1])\u003B\u000A            index++\u003B\u000A        }\u000A        \u000A        ans.push_back(newInterval)\u003B\u000A        \u000A        while(index \u003C len) ans.push_back(intervals[index++])\u003B\u000A\u000A        return ans\u003B \u000A    }\u000A}\u003B                         "
```

I would like to convert this string to C++ syntex and write to **solution.cpp** file.

The content in **solution.cpp** will look like..

```cpp
class Solution {
public:
    vector<vector<int>> insert(vector<vector<int>>& intervals, vector<int>& newInterval) {
        int len = intervals.size();
        int index = 0;
        vector<vector<int> > ans;
        

        while(index < len && intervals[index][1] < newInterval[0]) ans.push_back(intervals[index++]);
        
        while(index < len && intervals[index][0] <= newInterval[1]) {
            newInterval[0] = min(intervals[index][0], newInterval[0]);
            newInterval[1] = max(intervals[index][1], newInterval[1]);
            index++;
        }
        
        ans.push_back(newInterval);
        
        while(index < len) ans.push_back(intervals[index++]);

        return ans; 
    }
};
```

I have tried enforcing/converting encoding to `UTF-8` but the string stays the same.

```rb
code = File.read('code.txt')
code = code.encode('UTF-8')
file = File.open('solution.cpp', "w:UTF-8")
file.write(code)
```

How can I do this? Thank you.

Comment: `File.write("solution.cpp", eval(File.read("code.txt")))`, but don't do this anywhere important.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I have tried to reproduce your problem and got the same result as described by using your solution.

I have noticed that `\u003B` (for example) is a unicode code for semicolon character. So, I analyzed the string for each "U+" notation using regex `/\\u(.{4})/`, as it marks "hexadecimal digits" as being Unicode code points. Then used [gsub](https://apidock.com/ruby/String/gsub)! and [Array#pack](https://apidock.com/ruby/v2_5_5/Array/pack) to convert and substitute each of the Unicode chars.

```
[$1.to_i(16)].pack('U') # => "\n", "\n", "<", "&", "\n", "=" ...etc.
```

And finally wrote the result to a file. So, my final approach looks like this:

```
code = File.read('code.txt')

code.gsub!(/\\u(.{4})/) do |match|
  [$1.to_i(16)].pack('U')
end

File.open('solution.cpp', 'w') { |f| f.puts code.gsub!(/\A"|"\Z/, '') }
```

Also note, I have used `gsub` again at the end, to search for the leading or trailing quote and replace it with an empty string when writing to a file.